Does the time required to go through a security checkpoint count as break time?
In California, you are entitled to 2 uninterrupted 10 minute rest breaks and a 30 minute uninterrupted lunch break on a normal 8 hour shift.
However, if you work in a location that has security screening, and you have to take your break outside (which requires you to go through screening both ways), would that constitute a rest/meal break violation?
For example, if I am taking a break, I have to turn my radio in and sign a sheet with my break time (and clock out if it is a meal break). My break time starts once I sign or clock out, and I have to sign or clock back in in 10/30 minutes to end my break. During this allotted time for my break, I would have to go through screening twice.
Does the time spent going through security count as break time, or should break time start and stop when entering and leaving the break area?

Once you are past screening and outside is the break interrupted? Do you get a full 10 minutes outside before having to go back inside?  Ate you asking whether the 10 minutes clock starts when you leave your workstation, or when you get outside?

@MichaelHall I get 10 minutes from the time I turn my radio in and sign out for break. Same for meal break, except it's 30 minutes. I have to go through screening twice while on break, so I have to come back in early to get through screening in time to clock in at the right time.

That should be put into the question to make it more clear.

Yes, like Joe said.  Please explain better, because a momentary interruption is different than a shortening of the full allotted time due to administrative requirements on either end getting to and from the break area.  I think there's a good question in here WRT labor law, but it needs to be clarified.

@MichaelHall did my edit not address Joe's comment? what part still needs to be clarified?

Not fully.  See my edit and let me know if that is what you are really asking...

@MichaelHall yeah, basically. if time spent going through security counts as break time, or if only the time after i exit should count, and I am being given a too short of a break.

Are you actually required to leave the secure area for your break?  Or is it simply that the things you want to do on your break (buy food, smoke, etc) happen to be located outside the secure area?

@NateEldredge I am required to leave the screening area where I work for my break. There is a breakroom that is available for employees, however I do not have the correct badge to be able to go there yet. So I do currently have to leave the secure area for my break.
